# strange characters when pasting into terminal/fish shell: [200~ and [201~

Tags: linux, terminal, copy-paste, fish

When I paste something into [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd> I get strange characters. Here I pasted word "paste" into ranger:

[image]

And on the begining I have `[200~` and at the end `[201~`. I have no idea what could be the problem (ranger? fish shell? terminal? some config files?).
**How to get rid of unwanted characters while pasting?**

Some more info:
I use fish shell. Problem only persists when I start ranger with keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>. It works fine when I start ranger by manually entering commands `ranger` or `ranger_cd` or just by pasting text directly into fish shell (without starting ranger at all). <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> shortcut is defined by:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \co ranger_cd
end
```

My `ranger_cd` is function:

```
function ranger_cd
    set -l tempfile '/tmp/chosendir'

    ranger --choosedir $tempfile (pwd)
    if [ -f "$tempfile" ]; and [ (cat -- $tempfile) != (echo -n (pwd)) ]
        cd (cat $tempfile)
    end
    rm -f -- $tempfile
end
```

(its purpose is to save last dir chosen in ranger and cd into it after exiting ranger)

I also noticed that <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> doesn't work in ranger (it pastes only `^V`), but it works properly directly in fish shell (it pastes what I copied earlier, just as <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd>).

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you in advance. I use:

- Linux Manjaro 19.0.2 XFCE
- Xfce4 terminal 0.8.9.1
- fish 3.1.0
- ranger 1.9.2 (with python 3.6.9)

Comment: 200 and 201 fences are a consequence of "bracketed paste mode". https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste Sorry if it's not a full answer but it may offers you a nudge in the right direction for your searches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [bracketed paste mode](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste) indeed.

Fish enables it mainly to not execute multi-line pastes immediately. It disables it when you execute a command via the commandline and reenables it when you gain control again.

It's not typical to start interactive things via bindings, so fish doesn't disable it there.

To disable it manually, use `__fish_disable_bracketed_paste` and `__fish_enable_bracketed_paste`:

```
function ranger_cd
    set -l tempfile '/tmp/chosendir'

    __fish_disable_bracketed_paste
    ranger --choosedir $tempfile (pwd)
    __fish_enable_bracketed_paste
    if [ -f "$tempfile" ]; and [ (cat -- $tempfile) != (echo -n (pwd)) ]
        cd (cat $tempfile)
    end
    rm -f -- $tempfile
end
```

Comment: What is the name of the file to paste that part of code? Where is it located?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else is searching for this and isn't using fish shell, I just realised that if I accidentally try to paste into terminal with Ctrl-V it doesn't work and then remember to paste with Ctrl-Shift-V then that next paste will have
`^[[200~` at the start and `~` at the end. If I paste with just Ctrl-Shift-V it works fine.

Comment: More about the Bracketed-paste: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketed-paste

Answer (score -1):

Set terminal character encoding to UTF-8